# Is there any way to add multiple language(like french, spanish) in asp.net MVC website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web, web-applications

the website contains very large amount of data, so it is not possible to convert data in each language and paste it like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXlk1.png)

Comment: The problem is add all translations into resources or making your WebSite use translations?

Comment: is there any nuget packages available for that or i do i need to use translation extensions in chrome

Comment: I use this one https://github.com/Dresel/RouteLocalization